# Geocoding German Gemeindeschlüssel

Tags: geocoding, germany

Do you know a source where I can get a table for geocoding the numbers from German "Amtlicher Gemeindeschlüssel (AGS)" (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amtlicher_Gemeindeschl%C3%BCssel)?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve in detail, but you can get a vector of germany's administrative boundaries [here](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=15&gdz_user_id=0).
From point-level this should be enough. From address-level or if you stay <2500 requests/day .. maybe the google api?

Answer (score 3):

Since 2015 many things changed, as well as weblinks in the Wikipedia's article.

I hope that a `.xlsx`-file with *"Amtlicher Gemeindeschlüssel (AGS)"* can somehow assist. Data provider "Statistische Ämter des Bundes und der Länder".

You can find if here https://www.destatis.de/DE/Themen/Staat/Steuern/Steuereinnahmen/Publikationen/Downloads-Realsteuern/hebesaetze-realsteuern-8148001187005.html

Content look as following:

[image: content]

Geocode your addresses with an geocoder of your choice and than join data from above `.xlsx`-file via `"gemeinde"` as a key, before merge all subsheets in one.